# "Signature for this request is not valid."

Tags: variables, post, postman, binance

i have problem with api-rest in postman, i wanna use my {{sellPrice}} in request´s params. Everytime write [400 bad request img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmZjg.png), when i use normaly integer number it work good but with my variable {{sellPrice}} i got this error. i tried save this variable to global/enviroment/collections. It doenst work :(.[my params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmsxP.png).
Thanks for help.

This is my  [environment setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f2RW.jpg) + my [globals variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAdvt.png). I use GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHBUSD for refresh actualy price with script for set price to global variables[for set price to global variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh01G.png). This number re-write to my variables as well. Adding rewrite script´s  [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiBO1.png).

Variable sellPrice i want to use in POST [https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=ETHBUSD&price={{sellPrice}}&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.01&newClientOrderId=my_order_id_1&signature={{signature}}&timestamp={{timestamp}}](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=ETHBUSD&price=%7B%7BsellPrice%7D%7D&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.01&newClientOrderId=my_order_id_1&signature=%7B%7Bsignature%7D%7D&timestamp=%7B%7Btimestamp%7D%7D), where sellPrice is globalVariable.

Maybe in collection´s pre-request script can be something bad?

Comment: Hey! Please let us know which `API` you are using?

Comment: POST {{url}}/api/v3/order?symbol=ETHBUSD&price={{sellPrice}}&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.01&newClientOrderId=my_order_id_1&signature={{signature}}&timestamp={{timestamp}}

Comment: I meant the `url`

Comment: oh sorry i m really newbie .. this url i m ussing
https://api.binance.com/ , When i use normaly int number everything work good.

Comment: Click the **Environment quick look** (eye button) in the top right of Postman and click Edit next to Globals. Add a variable named `sellPrice` and give it an initial value . Click Save and close the environment modal.

Comment: which `API` of binance are you exactly using?

Comment: @MartinLukeš How do you generate the signature? Please edit your question and show the process. Redact any sensitive data such as api key/secret.

Comment: All added . I hope.

Comment: @MartinLukeš Do I understand it correctly that your signature is static, with no relation to values of the other parameters?

Comment: @PetrHejda Good afternoon i generating the signature in collection(binance spot api) i guess corectly in pre-request script where is ->const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  resolveQueryString(),
  pm.environment.get('binance-api-secret')
).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
pm.environment.set('signature', signature); I think this script is default.

Comment: @PetrHejda Yes , look like static . I didnt re-write anything from default setup. Everything with static params work as well. I mean if i will use normaly decimal number for example 1950.2 to price params everything work good, binance.api doenst have problem with my signature, troubles comming when i change decimal number to globalVariable {{sellPrice}}.

Comment: -> float is not good _ postman accept just decimal <- i hope it is sollution